# why typedef throwing error :(S) Initializer must be a valid constant expression

Tags: linux, gcc, aix, xlc

in **f1.h** header using typedef for structure. sample code snippet shown below

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    union u
    {
        int x;
        char y;
    }xyz;
}mystruct;
```

In **f2.h** header using the structure *mysturct* to get the offset. Code snippet shown below

```
static mystruct ktt

//#define OFFSET_T(b, c) ((int*)((&((mystruct*)0)->b)) - (int*)((&((mystruct*)0)->c)))
#define OFFSET_T(b, c) ((char*) &ktt.b - (char *) &ktt.c)

static struct Mystruct1{
    int n;
}mystruct1 = {OFFSET_T(xyz,a)};
```

when i'm doing compilation in **AIX** machine using **xlc** compiler it is throwing the error as **"1506-221(S) Initializer must be a valid constant expression"**.

i tried both the macro's but both are getting same error. Is there anything wrong in f2.h macro while performing size of structure to get offset ??

Answer (score 2):

The expression in question needs to be an arithmetic constant expression in order to be portable. Neither macro qualifies, since operands of pointer type are involved and arithmetic constant expressions are restricted such that those operands are not allowed. In C11, this is found in subclause 6.6 paragraph 8.

That said, the code using the first macro (source reproduced below) does compile on multiple versions of the `xlc` compiler on AIX.

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    union u
    {
        int x;
        char y;
    }xyz;
}mystruct;

static mystruct ktt;

#define OFFSET_T(b, c) ((int*)((&((mystruct*)0)->b)) - (int*)((&((mystruct*)0)->c)))
//#define OFFSET_T(b, c) ((char*) &ktt.b - (char *) &ktt.c)

static struct Mystruct1{
    int n;
}mystruct1 = {OFFSET_T(xyz,a)};
```

The compiler invocation I used was:

```
xlc offsetcalc.c -c -o /dev/null
```

The version information for one of the older versions I tried is:

```
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V10.1
Version: 10.01.0000.0021
```

The version information for one of the newest versions I tried is:

```
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V13.1.3 (5725-C72, 5765-J07)
Version: 13.01.0003.0004
```

Comment: @Tong, problem is not occurring of  with type casting. After replacing char* with int* also i'm getting the same error. "1506-221(S) Initializer must be a valid constant expression". So i hope problem is coming with something wrong in structure accessing with typedef.

Comment: @DeviPrasadDamarasingu, please indicate the compiler version, invocation, and source code used. Despite the Question title, the typedef is rather tangential to the question asked in the Question body. The status of both versions of the macro in terms of strictly conforming programs is described in my answer: the essence being that both macros are non-portable. It is true that you asked if there is anything wrong, so, the `int *` does mean that the offset is calculated in units of `sizeof(int)` bytes (which may be wrong). You may want to expand upon your reason for emphasizing "typedef".